# Error in passing parameters to stored procedure in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a stored procedure that I am calling which has three parameters, but for the life of me I do not see what is wrong with my syntax in C#:

```
var _accountREFCurrrent = new SqlParameter("@AccountRef", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    _accountREFCurrrent.Value = account.ACCOUNT_REF;

var _SortOrder = new SqlParameter("@SortOrder", SqlDbType.Int);
     _SortOrder.Value = first.SORT_ORDER;

var _CATEGORY = new SqlParameter("@CATEGORY", SqlDbType.Int);
     _CATEGORY.Value = first.CATEGORY;

var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<sp_sumbalances_Result>("sp_sumbalances_Result
@AccountRef @SortOrder @CATEGORY", new object[] { _accountREFCurrrent,
_CATEGORY  ,_SortOrder }).ToList();
```

It is probably something stupid. I now it's correct as it returns data in [SQL Server Management Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio):

[image]

Data being return from above in SQL Server Management Studio.

[image]

You will see the error I am getting in .NET:

[image]

Comment: Would you please share us the SQL Profiler result too? to see what is being delivered to SQL Server from .Net?

Comment: `@AccountRef @SortOrder @CATEGORY` should this not be `@AccountRef, @SortOrder, @CATEGORY` the commas are missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are commas missing between the parameters and the variables order is wrong:

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<sp_sumbalances_Result>("sp_sumbalances_Result
@AccountRef @SortOrder @CATEGORY", new object[] { _accountREFCurrrent,
_CATEGORY  ,_SortOrder }).ToList();
```

Should be:

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<sp_sumbalances_Result>("sp_sumbalances_Result
@AccountRef, @SortOrder, @CATEGORY", new object[] { _accountREFCurrrent, _SortOrder,
_CATEGORY}).ToList();
```